# Why imported Twilio in vuejs is invalid?

Tags: vuejs2, twilio

I want to use twilio API to my vuejs2 app looking at demo https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-node:
I added in in project with command
yarn add twilio

But I failed to create Twilio.Chat.Client with valid token, which I got from backendpoint,
as imported twilio object is invalid. In src/main.js I added line :

```
export const Twilio = require('twilio')
```

and in my vue page with code:

```
console.log('initializeChatClient token::')
console.log(token)
console.log('initializeChatClient id::')
console.log(id)
console.log('initializeChatClient channel::')
console.log(channel)

// const Twilio = require('twilio')
console.log('$twilio::')
console.log(Twilio)

console.log('$twilio.Chat::')
console.log(Twilio.Chat)

const client = await Twilio.Chat.Client.create(token)
```

I got error  :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Client' of undefined
```

and in console I see invalid twilio object : https://prnt.sc/w41cc7

What is wrong ?

package.json :

```
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"core-js": "^3.3.2",
...
"twilio": "^3.54.0",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, `Twilio` actually contains a function.
[image]

Check out this file: `https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-node/blob/master/src/notification_handler.js`:

There is this method that initialises the client using `new Twilio(...)`:

```js
function getTwilioClient() {
  // Twilio Library
  const client = new Twilio(
    config.TWILIO_API_KEY,
    config.TWILIO_API_SECRET,
    {accountSid: config.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID}
  );

  ...

}
```

Follow the same approach to initialise yours.